# Annoyance when running scripts in Vim (Windows, Ruby)

Tags: windows, ruby, vim, cmd

I started using vim for my programming projects (mostly Ruby) and mostly everything works just as I want but I have a problem with compiling.

Lets say I am working on a Ruby script and I want to run it. I type :ruby sometging.rb (mapped to some other key). Then vim opens a new cmd.exe window and runs 'ruby something.rb'. Then it waits for me to press ENTER to close the window and continue working on the script.

Is there a way to configure vim on windows so that it always runs the script I'm working on in a separete window (always the same one, if none exists => open one), and not ask me to confirm with enter?

Comment: I guess you mean gVim, because `vim` *called from the command prompt* will run the script in the same `cmd.exe` window (it will still wait for you to press ENTER to go back to the script though).

Comment: Yes, gVim. Sorry for not being precise.

Comment: I am curious, have you tried out Eclipse DLTK with Ruby support? That is what I am using on Windows without any problems.

Comment: You can do this in [screen.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2711), but I do not know how to use it on windows. The script page says that it is possible. You will obviously need screen or tmux installed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about gvim, but in normal vim you could put something like

`map R <ESC>:tabnew<CR><ESC>:;%!ruby filename.rb<CR>`

in your `~/.vimrc` which would execute a Ruby file in a newtab when pressing R in command mode.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used Ruby, but for I've found [Dr Chip's RunView plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2511) really useful for running other interpreted languages.

Once it's installed, you can enter:

```
:RunView! <interpreter>
```

(where `<interpreter>` is presumably 'ruby' in your case) and it will open a (vertically if you include the `!`) split window with the output from passing the contents of the current window to the interpreter.  Each time it is run, a new result log is appended to the end of the file (with a date and time stamp separating them).

If you have any issues with it, I'd recommend you contact [Dr Chip](http://mysite.verizon.net/astronaut/vim/) via the [Vim mailing list](http://www.vim.org/maillist.php#vim): he's very helpful (in fact he wrote the original version of RunView in response to [a request I made on the mailing list](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Filter-to-preview-window-td1143174.html)).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly perfect but I use this to launch Python scripts.

`command -nargs=* PY3 !start cmd /K Python.exe "%:p" <args>`

It starts up a window that stays alive and doesn't interfere with my VIM window. Unfortunately it doesn't load it into an existing window.